# Is there a way to direct unregistered user to registration page when click a link?

Tags: functions, user-registration, buttons, references

everyone:
this question seems pretty commmon to ask, but I did not find any answer.

I was wondering, if there is a php function that I could use to direct a user to the site's registartion page, so that I can use php instead of link that I need to customize every time I change the link.

THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, use the function [`is_user_logged_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in):

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

    <a hef="link-for-logged-users"></a>

  <?php } else { ?> 

    <a hef="link-for-users-not-logged-in"></a>

<?php } ?>
```

See here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in